# How to provide free begin/end functions for your own types

Tags: c++, c++11

In one of his latest talks, Herb Sutter recommended to prefer the free `begin(container)` `end(container)` functions templates over `container.begin()`. I like it, because these function can be provided for all iterable types that don't come with begin()/end() methods. Since most of my domain classes have interfaces that talk in the domain language and don't use general names like begin/end, I can now provide an iterable interface compatible to STL containers and range base for loops without messing up the main class interface.
I am wondering what is the best way to provide begin/end functions for my own types. My first thought was to do it the same way I do with `swap` and write the function in the same namespace where my type lives.

```
namespace My
{

class Book
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<Page>::const_iterator PageIterator;

    PageIterator FirstPage() const { return begin(pages_); }
    PageIterator LastPage() const { return end(pages_); }

private:
    std::vector<Page> pages_;
};

Book::PageIterator begin(const Book& b)
{
    return b.FirstPage();
}

Book::PageIterator end(const Book& b)
{
    return b.LastPage();
}

}
```

Is it ok to rely in ADL here, or should they be in std namespace? I think another way is to provide a specialization in std namespace (overloading in std is not allowed, right?). What is the best way espacially regarding lookup for range based for loops?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would let ADL do its work. While you are allowed to add specializations in the `std` namespace, there is no strong reason I can think of for doing so when a plain free function in  your namespace suffices.

In particular for the range for loops, the standard states:

> §6.5.4/1 (definition of *begin-expr* and *end-expr*):
>
> - otherwise, begin-expr and end-expr are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where begin and end are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2).  For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace std is an associated namespace.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly OK and recommended to "rely" on ADL. The `begin` and `end` functions are part of your type's interface (regardless of whether they are freestanding functions or not) and they should be in the same namespace as your type.