# How to iterate over a container that has no begin/end?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, c++98, gcc4.4

(C++98, gcc4.4.7)
Let's say I have a database-connected container that does not provide iterators over itself, but only an indexed getter and size(), ex:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class DbVector
{
public:
  const T& getValue(const size_t) const;
  size_t size() const;
};
```

I'd like to be able to use it in range-based algorithms. This sounds like a common problem. Does Boost provide a solution for this?

I've looked a bit into Boost.Iterator and Boost.Range, but with no success. I'm not even sure how my google query should be formulated to find anything useful.

I thought maybe there is a library, that would allow something like:

```cpp
typedef Iterable<DbVector<int>,
                 &DbVector<int>::getValue,
                 &DbVector<int>::size>
        IterableDbVectorInt;

const DbVector<int>& dbVector = getDbVector();
return boost::any_of_equal(IterableDbVectorInt(dbVector), someValue);
```

I know I could write it myself from scratch, but I'm really trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Any boost-based ideas?

Comment: Just provide `begin` and `end` free functions (with `r` and `c` variants) in the same namespace. I'm sure there's a duplicate, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I don't know Boost, but it seems that writing own iterator for this class would be relatively easy. You just need to store current index, provide `operator++` which increments the index and provide `operator*` which returns `getValue(currentIndex)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide free begin/end functions for your own types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582937/how-to-provide-free-begin-end-functions-for-your-own-types)

Comment: [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)/[std::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) ?

Comment: `boost::irange(v.size()) | boost::adaptors::transformed([&v](size_t i) -> const T& { return v.getValue(i); })` maybe?

Comment: Just noticed the restriction to gcc 4.4 / c++98 - you might be able to replace the lambda with `boost::bind(&DbVector<T>::getValue, boost::ref(v), boost::placeholders::_1)` and then hopefully it will still work.